# Scoped-slots, Accessing intance method

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a wrapper component where I bind a list from a vuex getter

```
<code>
  <grid-review-component v-bind:reviewResults="customerReviewResults">
    <grid-cell-component
     slot="cell"
     slot-scope="result" v-bind:label="result.getValue()"  v-bind:value="result.getValue">
    </grid-cell-component>
  </grid-review-component>
</code>
```

And in my grid-review-component i for loop and bind result

```
<div class="columns">
 <div class="column" v-for="result in reviewResults" :key="result.id">
   <slot name="cell" v-bind="result"></slot>
 </div>
</div>
```

The slot-scope binding works but getLabel() and getValue() are undefined; They are instance methods of a class; 
Not sure the reason for this, if I bind normally (parent to child instance gives me the correct values) but not this way. In this example err is they are not a function. What I am missing?